# How to add ScalaScriptEngine library in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have created a `libs` folder and placed `scalascriptengine-1.3.9-2.11.0.jar` in there. After that, I right-clicked on the `.jar` and selected `Add Library`.

Then, I created `Test.scala`:

```
import java.io.File

import com.googlecode.scalascriptengine.ScalaScriptEngine

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sourceDir = new File("examples/folder")
    val sse = ScalaScriptEngine.onChangeRefresh(sourceDir)
  }
}
```

It correctly recognized `ScalaScriptEngine`, or at least it did not give any warnings or errors. But it did not compile.

According to the [library page](https://code.google.com/p/scalascriptengine/) I edited my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "ScalaScriptEngineTest"

version := "1.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.googlecode.scalascriptengine" %% "scalascriptengine" % "1.3.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.11.1"
```

But upon refreshing, I get this: http://pastebin.com/GdirttUJ

What am I missing?  I am learning scala and it is the first time I am trying to add a library to IntelliJ Idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Change the two dependency entries in your `build.sbt` as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += 
  "com.googlecode.scalascriptengine" % "scalascriptengine" % "1.3.9-2.10.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.10.4"
```

Notice I didn't just change the versions -- I replaced your %% with a single %.

This results in you using a slightly older version of ScalaScriptEngine, and I don't know if that will cause any problems for you.

If you're using sbt build dependencies you don't need to be manually placing jars anywhere.

**Explanation:**

From your log I see that sbt is looking for the ScalaScriptEngine for Scala 2.10. In fact, it's pretty clear that you're running Scala 2.10.4, even though your sbt file expresses a dependency on the 2.11 compiler, which in fact is consistent with the instructions for using ScalaScriptEngine.

On line 23 of the log you can see exactly where it's looking. If you point your browser part way down [that path](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/scalascriptengine/) you'll see that there is a version for Scala 2.11 and another directory, scalascriptengine, without a version qualifier. If you dive down the latter, you'll see it's where they keep all the old versions. There isn't a ScalaScriptEngine 1.3.10 (the one you asked for) compiled for Scala 2.10, so your options seem to be to upgrade to Scala 2.11 (which I don't think currently works if you want to use IntelliJ Idea's tight integration with sbt), or you can use ScalaScriptEngine 1.3.9.

You have basically the same problem with your Scala compiler dependency -- it needs the be the Scala version you're using.

I've confirmed the above solution with Scala 2.10.4. I'm playing it a little fast and loose because there isn't a pre compiled version for 2.10.4, and I gambled that the 2.10.3 build will probably work.

**Alternatives:**

There may be a cleaner way to solve this, but the way the repository is organized makes me doubt it.

You could build the version of your choice with the compiler of your choice, or persuade the ScalaScriptEngine community to do it for you and put it in The Central Repository, but my guess is that 1.3.10 won't build with anything lower than Scala 2.11.

Finally, if you do want to download jars by hand, you may want to read the "Unmanaged dependencies" section of the [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html). Actually, if you're going to use sbt, just read the whole thing a few times.